# The share via email option has disappeared in GPlus

Tags: google-plus

There used to be a little box you could check to share your Google Plus post via email that's not there for me anymore - It just disappeared.

Any idea how to get it back?

Comment: From what I recall, this was only available when you were sharing to a specific Circle.